# DataTable silently failing to initialize

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm struggling to get my head around the jQuery DataTables library. I've finally got an AJAX call working with a Web Forms Web Method (ugly I know), and I'm receiving a JSON response successfully, but the table is empty.  What have I done wrong?

I have a simple table like so:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Launch Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Launch Name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And I'm initializing the data table on documentready:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "dom": "frtS",
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "deferRender": true,
    "ajax": {
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "Default.aspx/GetSearchResults",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            return $.parseJSON(json.d);
            //return json.d;
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ProjectID" },
            { "data": "ProjectName" },
            { "data": "ProjectLaunchName" }
        ]
    }
});
```

And my JSON response is valid (according to the DataTables specs, the JSON requires a root 'data' object), for instance:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ProjectID": 100850,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test Project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test Project",
            "Status": "Deleted"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: JSON object in Google]

I'm unable to get the table to populate, despite following all examples I've found. I'm not getting any error messages, the table just has 0 rows in it. Have I missed something obvious? I've tried to use the standard `json.d` response, instead of parsing it, but that fails as well.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I use the below .NET Web Forms WebMethod (again, terrible I know, but my hand is forced) to return the JSON object from the server.  Note how I wrap the JSON with the data object to conform to the spec in DataTables documentation:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetSearchResults() As String
    Dim bo As New Business.ProjectSearch
    Dim searchCriteria As New Entities.ProjectSearchCriteria

    Dim searchResults As List(Of Entities.ProjectSearchResult) = bo.SearchProjects(searchCriteria, 1).Take(10).ToList()

    Dim wrapper = New With {Key .data = searchResults}
    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper)
End Function
```

The full JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ProjectID": 101296,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test Project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "asdasdkljasd",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": null,
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101295,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101294,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": null,
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101293,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2018-01-31T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101292,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101291,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Deleted",
            "LaunchDate": null,
            "ProjectClassification": 4,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101290,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101289,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2017-02-28T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101288,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Terminated",
            "LaunchDate": "2018-04-30T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 3,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        },
        {
            "ProjectID": 101287,
            "ActivityTypeID": 1,
            "ProjectName": "Test project",
            "ProjectLaunchName": "Test project",
            "Status": "Active",
            "LaunchDate": "2016-01-31T00:00:00",
            "ProjectClassification": 0,
            "PageUrl": "ProductInnovation.aspx"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also found that if I create a text file on the server containing the above JSON, DataTables initialized successfully:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajaxSource": "data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
      { "data": "ProjectID" },
      { "data": "ProjectName" },
      { "data": "ProjectLaunchName" }
    ]
});
```

Additionally, the requested `console.log(json)` screenshot below.  Clearly it can't be right. Note that this line of code is added BEFORE the json object manipulation.

[image]

If I comment out the `for()` loop that manipulates the JSON, the `console.log(json)` looks correct, which is strange because the manipulation occurs after console.log:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm on v1.10.7, which is the latest.

Comment: is that your actual code? why are you parsing your json? and why is json.d instead of json.data? try just with "dataSrc": function (json) {
            return json.data);  and tell me how it went.

Comment: Yes, it is my actual code. I was having trouble with my implementation so I adapted some of the example documentation - will revise it once it's actually working. The JSON.NET call that I'm using to return the JSON wraps the object in an entity called `d` for whatever reason. If I try to `return json.data` or `json.d.data`, I 'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` at jquery.dataTables.min.js:164, which is very cryptic.

Comment: check the comma at the end of your json response : "Status": "Deleted", <- this comma. That makes the json invalid.

Comment: My mistake - copy and paste error. There are some additional fields that I omitted, but the full response would look something like this (assuming 1 project): `{"data":[{"ProjectID":101296,"ActivityTypeID":1,"ProjectName":"Test Project","ProjectLaunchName":"asdasdkljasd","Status":"Active","LaunchDate":null,"ProjectClassification":0,"PageUrl":"ProductInnovation.aspx"}]}`

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Use initialization code below instead:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "dom": "frtS",
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "deferRender": true,
    "ajax": {
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "Default.aspx/GetSearchResults",
        "data": function (d) {
           return JSON.stringify(d);
        },
        "dataSrc": function(json){
           json = $.parseJSON(json.d);

           return json.data;
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ProjectID" },
            { "data": "ProjectName" },
            { "data": "ProjectLaunchName" }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: With this approach, `json.data` is undefined when returned and the `json` object contains an array of single characters. I feel like I have to do some sort of transformation on the json object though.

Comment: @TimeBomb006, can you put `console.log(json)` before `for(... in ...)` and post the output here? Your server-side code producing the JSON would be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've updated my original post with the `console.log(json)` results (looks to be incorrect), the server side code producing the JSON, and some additional information.

Comment: @TimeBomb006, I made corrections to my solution based on the details that you've provided, please give it a try. In the meantime I think your server-side code needs to be changed, but I'm not sure how yet.

Comment: Thanks again. With this approach, it's rendering ten empty rows (correct for how many items are returned from my WebMethod) and DataTables is throwing the following cryptic error - `DataTables warning: table id=example = Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`. Looking under the `Parameter is an integer` section, it seems that there's some sort of issue reading from the json object.